# Conceptual question regarding liminf and limsup for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_j\}$ be a sequence of Real Numbers.
Now we define:

$\lim_{j \to \infty}\inf a_j = \lim_{j \to \infty}A_j$

Where $A_j = \inf\{a_j, a_{j+1}, a_{j+2}, \cdots \}$

Now in a line of a proof about a page away, text says to me:

> There is a $j_1 \geq 1$ such that $|A_{j_1} - a_{j_1}|  < 2^{-1}$

I don't see how this follows from the definition, and so, perhaps, there is something I have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you may recall what is the definition of infimum. From the definition, you can find a $s_k$ as close to the inf as you want, so there should exist the distance between the $A_k$ and $a_k$

Comment: :/ ... -_- ...
At least I got to practice my LaTex.
Thanks.